# Disable 'Recently Entered Values' Dropdown For <input> Fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropdown, create-react-app

I'm currently building an application in React and it appears, that by default, the input fields save recently entered values and show them as a dropdown when you go back to the field later like so:

[image]

I for the life of me can't figure out how to disable this functionality. Is this a browser feature or can I disable this in my code? It's very much in the way of other components and I'm surprised how little I can find online about this menu.

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I know! this is so annoying... I hate when chrome shows this and it goes over the actual dropdown list of values. some forms won't validate if you use this browser auto-complete but only if an option is manually selected from the list.

Comment: Related - [Disabling Chrome Autofill](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15738259/104380)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disabling Chrome Autofill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill)